# Typecasting in Javascript / google closure library

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-closure-library

I am passing a complex object consisting of `goog.structs.Set` from my content script to background page through `chrome.extension.SendMessage` API. On the other side, this `goog.structs.Set` is received as an `Object`.
How can I typecast it back to `goog.structs.Set` so that I can call various methods on it?

Comment: Before sending the complex object, I convert goog.structs.Set to an array. See @John answer's below for an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html, you can only pass JSON using chrome.extension.SendMessage.

Personally, I use a simple object as a set and avoid goog.structs.Set:

```
var MySet = Object.create(null);
```

If use must use goog.structs.Set, you will need to serialize and deserialize it to JSON.

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "I use a simple object as a set and avoid goog.structs.Set". I use Set because I do not want duplicate entries. Do you mean to implement "unique entries" property in simple object yourself?

Comment: If object can be part of JSON and everything in javascript is Object, (Objects are just data, with properties and methods.. From W3schools) then why Set is not an object?

Comment: W3schools is a bad reference.  JSON is a subset of JavaScript, the objects can only include Objects, Array, and primitive data (string number, bool).

Comment: Specifically, it can not have properties that are functions.  As a object can not contain duplicate properties it is naturally a set.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean for the closure compiler?

```
function receiveStructsSet( aSetObject ){

    var mySet =  /** @type {goog.structs.Set} */ (aSetObject); 
}
```

Comment: Make sure to note the extra parenthesis.

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. closure-compiler is not involved in my problem. I am passing a set object from content script to background page in chrome extension. In background page, set is only received as an object and I am not able to call set-specific methods on that object.

Comment: I see. In that case I would probably only pass the data and make a new `struct.Set` from that on the other side.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the annotation before the function declaration

```
/**
 *  @param {goog.structs.Set} aSetObject description of object
 */
function receiveStructsSet( aSetObject ){
  aSetObject.getCount();
}
```